# Installing modules in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Suppose I have a directory with custom .py files. The directory is called useful_scripts and a subdirectory called tested_scripts which also contains scripts (.py files).

I've seen on some articles, import statements like:

```
from useful_scripts.tested_scripts import sth
```

How could we install our custom directory modules in such a convienient way so that we could access it like above?

Comment: put a `__init__.py` in the folder

Comment: Make a dir useful_scripts with a subdir tested_scrips where you put your script sth.py.

Add useful_scripts to your PYTHONPATH and put an (empty) \_\_init\_\_.py in both useful_scripts and useful_scripts/tested_scripts.

If you'd rather not add anything to your PYTHONPATH you can also add useful_scripts to sys.path programmatically.

Comment: Write a `setup.py` and install it?

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge, how do I edit my PYTHONPATH? And what is this __init__.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple modules (Python file with .py ) in directory and want to import  one module in another module then first define that directory to a python directory or package

Packages are namespaces which contain multiple packages and modules.Each package in Python is a directory which MUST contain a special file called **__init__.py**

**[Python Package](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/package)**

Your directory structure should be like this if you want to import modules or package

[image]

Now you can import module a.py in module b.py or module b.py in module a.py

If you want to install custom lib then create **setup.py** the file where coustomlib directory exists ( create setup.py outside the coustomlib directory or along coustomlib )

in **setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='coustomlib',
  version='1.0',
  description='Python coustom lib ',
  author='your name',
  author_email='name@mail.in',
  packages=find_packages(),
 )
```

for install run

```
python setup.py install
```

After install coustomlib you can import it any module

```
import coustomlib
```

Or

```
from coustomlib.module1 import a
```

More info about **[setup.py](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)**

Comment: @Kaliz, why can the __init__.py be empty?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal its already answer here  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for'