# Importing a custom module from a different directory within the same project

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a custom module but for some reason I can't get it to work and I'm getting an `ImportError`.

My directory structure is like so:

```
MyProject
  - MyProject
    - bin
      scraper.py
    - myproject
      __init__.py
      CustomModule.py
  - web
    index.html
  - venv
```

I'm attempting to import `CustomModule.py` from `scraper.py`. Ideally without having to set any environment variables, or using `sys.path`.

This is what I've tried:

```
import CustomModule
from myproject import CustomModule
from ..myproject import CustomModule
```

Is this possible?

Comment: did you ry putting a init file in the directory where scraper.py is?

Comment: Try to put "CustomModule.py" and  "scraper.py" at the same level (in the same folder).

Comment: Is this python 2 or python 3? Are any of these folders in your `sys.path`? Is `scraper.py` the `__main__` file?

Comment: @ZiMtyth all my modules will live in a different directory to the bin directory. That's not what I want.

Comment: See the bottom of this page https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories  , maybe you can find what you want

Comment: may this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768862/installing-modules-in-python-3

Comment: Try import myproject.CusomModule. from statements work differently in python 3. Bar that. You cannot go up one level...

Comment: Move scraper.py up one level you will be able to use my suggestion. It proves that your directory structure is not adapted to how python works.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I disagree. `scraper.py` belongs in the `bin` directory. along with other applications intended to be ran from the terminal. Python does have a solution (Yohan's comment). Python has no definitive requirements to project structure, only guidelines. If, like me, you want to do things differently ... it can handle that too. My original question was to ask if it could be done without using `sys.path.append` (which I was already using)

Comment: as you want, it's your project after all. It's just that "parent directory" cannot be a module. You could set pythonpath too.

Answer (score 1):

Taking [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre)'s comment into account, if no solution without sys.path is provided, consider using:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','myproject'))
import CustomModule
```

Comment: Thanks, I am already doing that but I wanted to know if it was possible without using `sys.path`. I did mention that in the question.

Comment: .. is a bad choice. What if current directory is not the one of the current module?

Comment: I agree this solution is "current directory"-dependent. @Jean-FrançoisFabre, what would you suggest?

Comment: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','myproject')`