# import cannot find same folders' files

Tags: python

import cannot find same file.Now,I have a,b,c files in folder A.
File a　read b&c ones.First,I wrote in file a like

```
import b
import c
   ・
　 ・
　 ・   
x = b_method()
y = c_method()
```

But,error happens "No module named b".Next,I wrote in file a like

```
from A import b
from A import c
　　　・
    　・
    　・   
x = b_method()
y = c_method()
```

But,when I run this file,terminal said

```
ImportError: No module named 'A'
```

So,how can I read file b&c in file a?
How can I fix this?
I added

```
import os
import sys
file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(file_dir)
```

to file a,but it does not work.

My project structure is

```
test   (parent app)
｜--- A
      |
      ---- a
      ---- b
      ---- c
```

Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    from A import b
ImportError: No module named 'A'
```

When i wrote `import b`,
Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 58, in <module>
    xxx = b.parse(user, id)
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Whole a.py is

```
import sys
import os
import b
import c


LOG_FILENAME = 'excel.log'
file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(file_dir)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=2000000, backupCount=5, encoding='utf-8')
handler.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'))
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(console)

# READ
def read_config():
    f = codecs.open('config.json', 'r', 'utf-8')
    text = f.read()
    config = json.loads(text)
    return config

try:
    logger.debug('start.')
    logger.info("--------------------------------")
    logger.info("Excelファイル読込処理を開始します。")
    logger.info("--------------------------------")
    config = read_config()
    output_dir = config['output_dir']

    logger.info("クライアントのデータを読み込みます。")
    book_name = config['client']['file_name']
    regions = config['client']['regions']
    #clientsが空だと、jsonがoutputされない
    xxx = b.parse(user, id)
    yyy = c.parse(name,mail)
    logger.info("--------------------------------")

# ERROR
except:
    logger.exception('exception occurred.')
    print(input("error"))
    sys.exit(-1)

logger.debug('end.')
print(input("finish"))
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you please show your current directory structure? Also, are you sure that the script in which you are importing the modules is in the same directory as the modules?

Comment: You have a lot of problems, but to address them, please show us what your directory structure looks like.

Comment: If you want help, we need more info. The biggest being, what is your project structure?

Comment: A is directory not a class or module while importing provide full path of file like import path

Comment: @SamChats thx ur comments.Iadded my info

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thx ur comments.Iadded my info

Comment: @ChristianDean thx ur comments.Iadded my info

Comment: @user8504021 Also, for _both_ errors, please show the complete traceback, instead of just the error.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i added my complete traceback.if u know something,please help me

Comment: Yes, the second problem is easily explained. But the `No module named b` is not. Please add that traceback too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i added my whole completely traceback

Comment: No, you haven't added the traceback for `import b`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oh,i understand ur meanings,sorry.I added my traceback info.

Comment: @user8504021 Okay. this is _not_ an ImportError. It has to do with your code. Next, you should post the whole of your `a.py` code here, or the parts relevant to the traceback.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I updated  whole a.py

Comment: first, define __init__.py in A module and then check  answers in question where I explain about Python package and directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768862/installing-modules-in-python-3

Comment: @Kallz I added init.py into folder A,but same error happened when i wrote from A import b & import b.How can I do for next?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of two things:
-- The files you are trying to import are in the same folder/directory as the file you are working in
-- The files are something you can use with python (a .py file is what you should be using)

After making sure of that try this on idle:

```
>>> import b
>>> import c
>>> c
>>> b
```

After doing that python should give you a message telling you about the specific modules

Answer (score 0):

Making an empty file `__init__.py` in the directory and Python can identift directory from which you're allowed to import. Then you use

```
import b
import c
```

Comment: thx,ur comments.I added __init__.py into folder A,but same error happened when i wrote from A import b & import b.How can I do for next?